# Try to change data in Laravel's pagination → item but fail, how can I solve it?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I making Restful API with Laravel

I tried to change data in pagination result

**My code**

```php
$rooms->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
    if (!$item->last_message) {
        $item->last_message = (object) array('updated_at' => ''.$item->updated_at);
    }
    $item->test0 = $item->id;
    $item->test1 = $item->last_message;
    $item->test2 = \json_encode($item->last_message);
    $item->test3 = \json_encode($item);
    return $item;
});
```

I expected that `$item->last_message` will equals to `item->updated_at`
but the result always `null`

Here is json result

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 33,
      "user_id": 1,
      "seller_id": 3,
      "room_id": 1,
      "market_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2019-05-02 10:23:29",
      "updated_at": "2019-05-02 10:23:29",
      "last_message": null,
      "test0": 33,
      "test1": {
        "updated_at": "2019-05-02 10:23:29"
      },
      "test2": "{\"updated_at\":\"2019-05-02 10:23:29\"}",
      "test3": "{\"id\":33,\"user_id\":1,\"seller_id\":3,\"room_id\":1,\"market_id\":1,\"created_at\":\"2019-05-02 10:23:29\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-05-02 10:23:29\",\"last_message\":null,\"test0\":33,\"test1\":{\"updated_at\":\"2019-05-02 10:23:29\"},\"test2\":\"{\\\"updated_at\\\":\\\"2019-05-02 10:23:29\\\"}\"}"
    }
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http://localhost/v2/users/1/chat-rooms?page=1",
  "from": 1,
  "last_page": 1,
  "last_page_url": "http://localhost/v2/users/1/chat-rooms?page=1",
  "next_page_url": null,
  "path": "http://localhost/v2/users/1/chat-rooms",
  "per_page": 15,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": 1,
  "total": 1
}
```

Notice that I can get data from `$item->last_message` to set data to `$test1` but when parsing object to JSON the `$item->last_message` data will be `null`

How can I solve it, Thank you

Comment: what is `last_message ` referring to in Room class

Comment: data.['test1'][0] ?

Comment: @usrNotFound

The room is chat room, it's the last message from chat room, `last_message` will be `null` when no messages in this room, but I try to set `updated_at` value to make it able to show last message time at client side

Comment: @Ahmed Aboud I can get data but `last_message` data always null, see the JSON result

Comment: have you tried just assigning its $item->last_message = $item->updated_at before encoding ?

Comment: @Ahmed Aboud Tried but it's still null

Answer (score 0):

from Laravel doc

> Unlike most other collection methods, transform modifies the
>   collection itself. If you wish to create a new collection instead, use
>   the map method.

So, I would suggest you to use map like so

```
$rooms->getCollection()->map(function ($item) {
  if (!$item->last_message) {
    $item->last_message = (object) array('updated_at' => ''.$item->updated_at);
  }
  $item->test0 = $item->id;
  $item->test1 = $item->last_message;
  $item->test2 = \json_encode($item->last_message);
  $item->test3 = \json_encode($item);
  return $item;
});
```

Comment: I will let you figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

As I find in Laravel codes it may have functions that can change result of `json_encode()` result, so I decided to parse paginated value to json then parse to array object to change data and finally parse back to json for response

**My code**

```
// Parse to JSON then parse back to array object 
// To make sure the format is correct (Same as Laravel standard)
$json = $rooms->toJson();
$parsedJson = \json_decode($json, true);
$items = $parsedJson['data'];
$count = count($items);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $item = $items[$i];
    if (!$item['last_message'])
    {
        $item['last_message'] = array(
            'message' => 'Has joined the chat', /* TODO: may change this message later */
            'created_at' => $item['created_at'], 
            'updated_at' => $item['updated_at']);
    }
    $parsedJson['data'][$i] = $item;
}
```

Comment: SO, you know in the future you could have used collection's `map ` pipeline to achieve what you did here. and thats what my answer was. @ltttipon Teerapruettikulchai